# Mac on Linux, is it legal?

Tags: virtualization, macosx

While browsing i found an interesting [tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mac-on-linux/) in sourceforge.net
it says

> Mac-on-Linux is a Linux/PPC program that virtualizes MacOS or MacOSX in Linux.

Is it legal? If yes how to install it in Ubuntu?

Comment: Where do you live?

Comment: India ,
is it important?

Comment: "is legal" means "allowed by applicable law". In India, the applicable law is indian law.

Comment: I wonder why you ask this question, when you live in India.

Comment: @nikhil
what you mean?

Comment: There aren't many laws that are enforced against piracy and copyright here are they?
You are doing something that is neither so you needn't worry.

Comment: *"Is it legal"* is a **good question**. *"How to install**. Please post it separately, and maybe post a link here. :)

Comment: Man, Apple OS and hardware always restrictive! Why would you want run Mac. At least ubuntu is far better than Mac!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's against the EULA, but in general, each provision of a EULA is treated separately (at least, according to Wikipedia), i.e. so a part of a EULA might be found to be legally non-binding.  The legality depends on where you are, but if you're in the US, I would guess it's illegal because of the DMCA.  Apple sued a clone manufacturer([Psystar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psystar_Corporation)) several years ago for selling machines with OS X installed on them.  They sued under several different legal reasons, but one of them was that Apple uses encryption methods protected under the DMCA to keep OS X from being installed on non-Apple hardware.  The court found that indeed the DMCA was violated and Apple won.

Comment: Great answer , I am from india ,whats the case with india?

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 8):

It is definitely a EULA violation. Violating a license agreement is like violating a contract. It gives Apple the right to sue you. Will they? Probably not. As long as you aren't getting in the way of their business. So is it illegal? I would say yes. Is it criminal? No.
It's simply a civil contract violation. You have to make up your own mind. Personally, I suggest just getting some Apple hardware because it's great.

Comment: +1 for Apple hardware! (though is somewhat more expensive)

Comment: An EULA violation is only illegal for the asker if the relevant provision is enforceable under Indian law.

Answer (score 6):

Legal or not is a grey area for OSX on non-Apple hardware. I think, for personal use, the most that will happen is that they won't give you tech support

Comment: A doubt ,if linux is installed in the apple hardware and installing mac in side that linux,is it legal?

Comment: It is, probably. EULA prohibits installation/running of OSX on non-apple hardware.

Comment: @I'mnotthisperson, Yea, unless you were selling these, then Mac on Linux on Mac will at worst give them grounds to restrict tech support.

Answer (score 2):

Mac on Linux works on PowerPC processor. It is not designed to work on x86 processor family. In practice, the question is "Is it legal to run Mac On Linux" on old Apple Hardware? Apple stops PPC in 2006 !

Answer (score 0):

I have an old PPC iMac, and I tried installing Ubuntu on it.  It sort of worked, but barely, and a lot of programs won't run - even things like Google's Picasa requires an Intel CPU.  Yellow Dog Linux is about the only supporter of Linux on PPC these days, and it's not easy to get it working.

So, finding non-Apple PPC hardware, and then getting Ubuntu to run on it would probably be harder than any potential legal battle with Apple.  :)

Comment: it's the other way around.